# Are the constraints that you set guaranteed to work 100% of the time?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I was finishing up adding constraints to my application and came up with a question regarding them. After I set up my constraints in X-Code and test them for all devices using the simulator, is it guaranteed that my application will look the way that it was displayed in X-Code & on the simulator on all devices that download it? Has anyone ever set constraints that look fine in X-Code & on the simulator but look completely different when on an actual device? Perhaps I'm overthinking the process, but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: Constraints wont be different in phone and simulator.If it works in simulator will be same in phone also.

Comment: If it could be different in device from Simulator, what would you do? Get one of every device type???

Comment: While it's true that "there are no guarantees", the very few times I've seen questions on SO claiming there's a difference, they can be either (1) a flawed layout constraint that fell through the cracks, (2) improper/incomplete  testing - think iPhone SE, iPad split screen or slide out - or (3) a *very obscure* bug on Apple's end. Usually, like the first two, it's the fault of the developer. When it comes to constraints, it's very likely that **anything** ill-behaved on a device can be duplicated on the simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , constraints are used for auto layout. It depends of who type of constraint you have given. But if it is Properly working on simulator than it will also perfectly work on Device, too.